# How to remove "\" as string in python

Tags: python, string, special-characters

I am trying to remove the backslash from a string but because the character is special it won't work. I want it to print "example".

```
example = ("e\x\m\p\l\e")
example=example.replace("\","")
print(example)
```

Comment: `"e\x\m\p\l\e"` will raise a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
example = (r"e\x\m\p\l\e")
example=example.replace("\\","")
```

You can use a literal string using `r`, and then use replace with the special character using `\\` (double backslash).

EDIT:

One can also use regex to remove all `\`:

```
import re
''.join(re.findall(r'[^\\]', example))
```

The findall will result in an list with all characters. You can use join to transform this list to a string.

```
''.join(re.findall(r'[^\\]', r'e\x\m\p\l\e this is an \exmaple. \\ test'))
>>> exmple this is an exmaple.  test
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use double \ to escape the special symbol:

```
example=example.replace("\\","")
```